# Only the last page of text gets printed from a longer web page in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, printing

I have a long web page. When i lauch a printing in Mozilla Firefox the last page only of text gets printed and the rest are a blank pages.

Comment: Can you share the page url?

Comment: Please share the example/ some code to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Abdullah requested, it would be beneficial to see a page that exhibits this problem. Also, what version of Firefox and what platform are you on?

From the brief description of the problem it could be:

- Something with HTML or CSS of the page
- A bug in the OS
- A bug in Firefox
- A problem with the printer driver.

To rule out the printer or printer driver, I would recommend using a virtual printer driver that lets you create a file such as XPS or PDF from the printed web page. I tested a couple of "long" sites (around 30 pages printed) using the print preview feature of my EPSON R2000 printer, and all 30 pages appeared.

Here's a list of virtual printer drivers that might be able to help you diagnose the problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software

I'm assuming you tried this, but still want to know for certain, does this happen in other browsers for the same page?

If it is Firefox-specific and happens on multiple pages, I would also suggest trying [older Firefox versions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox). If it works in an older version of Firefox, then you should [report the problem as a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).